# Splits a priority queue into two with values going to alternating priority queues. The split is stable.

Tags: python-3.x, split

Splits a priority queue into two with values going to alternating priority queues. The split is stable.(within class)
class PriorityQueue:

```
def __init__(self):
    """
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Initializes an empty priority queue.
    Use: pq = PriorityQueue()
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Postconditions:
        Initializes an empty priority queue.
    -------------------------------------------------------
    """
    self._values = []
    self._first = None
    return

def is_empty(self):
    """
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Determines if the priority queue is empty.
    Use: b = pq.is_empty()
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Postconditions:
        returns
        True if priority queue is empty, False otherwise.
    -------------------------------------------------------
    """
    return len(self._values) == 0

def __len__(self):
    """
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Returns the length of the priority queue.
    Use: n = len(q)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Postconditions:
        returns
        the number of values in the priority queue.
    -------------------------------------------------------
    """
    return len(self._values)

def insert(self, value):
    """
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Inserts a copy of value into the priority queue.
    Use: pq.insert(value)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Preconditions:
        value - a data element (?)
    Postconditions:
        a copy of value is added to the priority queue.
    -------------------------------------------------------
    """
    self._values.append(deepcopy(value))
    if self._first is None:
        self._first = 0
    elif value < self._values[self._first]:
        self._first = len(self._values) - 1
    # your code here

    return

def remove(self):
    """
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Removes and returns value from the priority queue.
    Use: v = pq.remove()
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Postconditions:
        returns
        value - the highest priority value in the priority queue -
        the value is removed from the priority queue. (?)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    """
    assert len(
        self._values) > 0, "Cannot remove from an empty priority queue"

    value = self._values.pop(self._first)
    n = len(self._values)
    if n == 0:
        self._first = None
    else:
        self._first = 0
        for i in range(1, n):
            if self._values[self._first] > self._values[i]:
                self._first = i
    return value

def peek(self):
    """
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Peeks at the highest priority value of the priority queue.
    Use: v = pq.peek()
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Postconditions:
        returns
        value - a copy of the highest priority value in the priority queue -
        the value is not removed from the priority queue. (?)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    """
    assert len(self._values) > 0, "Cannot peek at an empty priority queue"
    value = deepcopy(self._values[self._first])
    # your code here

    return value

def split_key(self, key):
    """
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Splits a priority queue into two depending on an external
    priority key. The split is stable.
    Use: pq2, pq3 = pq1.split_key(key)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Preconditions:
        key - a data object (?)
    Postconditions:
        returns
        pq2 - a priority queue that contains all values
            with priority less than key (PriorityQueue)
        pq3 - priority queue that contains all values with
            priority greater than or equal to key (PriorityQueue)
        The current priority queue is empty
    -------------------------------------------------------
    """
    pq2 = PriorityQueue()
    pq3 = PriorityQueue()

    while len(self._values) > 0:
        v = self._values.pop()

        if v <= key:
            pq3.insert(v)

        else:
            pq2.insert(v)
        self._first -= 1
    while not pq2.is_empty():
        print("pq2  {}".format(pq2.peek()))

    self._first = None
    # your code here

    return pq2, pq3

def split(self):
    """
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Splits a priority queue into two with values going to 
            alternating priority queues. The split is stable.
    Use: pq2, pq3 = pq1.split()
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Postconditions:
        returns
        pq2 - a priority queue that contains alternating values
            from the current queue (PriorityQueue)
        pq3 - priority queue that contains  alternating values
            from the current queue  (PriorityQueue)
        The current priority queue is empty
    -------------------------------------------------------
    """
    pq2 = PriorityQueue()
    pq3 = PriorityQueue()

    i = 0

    while len(self._values) > 0 and not self.is_empty():

        if i % 2 == 0:

            pq2.insert(self._values.pop(0))

        else:

            pq3.insert(self._values.pop(0))

        i += 1
    self._first = None

    return pq2, pq3
```

------I m not getting right answer for split function and split_key functions. I apprieciate your help.

example of data: 
pq1 = 4,1,7,3,9,2,4,1,7,0,9
splits into:
pq2 = 4,7,9,4,7,9 
pq3 = 1,3,2,1,0

Comment: You are getting the expected answer. pq1 splits into pq2 and pq3 alternating values. What do you want to get??

Comment: yes ,i get right answer with that but split is not stable which the order of output numbers are not right